# RHEL6 Can't make my script run on shutdown and reboot

Tags: rhel, shutdown, chkconfig

I'm trying to execute a script in each shutdown and reboot but the script never runs.

1. I created the script baseRhel64 and save it to `/etc/rc.d/init.d`
2. I did `chkconfig --add baseRhel64`
3. I included in the script

   ```
   #chkconfig --list
   # chkconfig: 06 10 10
   ```
4. I verified that the S10 script where created under `/etc/rc0.d/S10baseRhel64` and `/etc/rc6.d/S10baseRhel64`

The following is my script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

#chkconfig --list
# chkconfig: 06 10 10

start(){
    echo "`basename $0` start"
    touch /root/installscripts/test1
}

stop(){
    echo "`basename $0` stop"
    touch /root/installscripts/test2
    touch /root/installscripts/"`basename $0`"
}

case "$1" in
    start) start;;
    stop) stop;;
    *) 
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
    RETCAL=1
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: I think the init script needs to follow a certain header format, see an example here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:SysVInitScript?rd=Packaging/SysVInitScript#Initscript_template

Comment: It may also be helpful to note that you should still have a `;;` at the end of your default (`*)`) `case`.

Comment: I tried following https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:SysVInitScript?rd=Packaging/SysVInitScript#Initscript_template but still didn't manage.

Comment: service baseRhel64 start | stop | status all work fine but not during shutdown and restart

Comment: Did it show up when you ran chkconfig? Does the runlevels stated correspond with what you're running?? Is it true you want it only during reboot 6 and 0halt? Add some debugging to it ie redirect stdout and stderr to see if it gets called and what args are in $1

Answer (score 2):

When you configure a custom init script in RH EL 6, named for example "service_name", you have to care to create, during its start phase, the lock file 
/var/lock/subsys/service_name
otherwise the script will not be executed during shutdown of the system (init 0 or init 6).
At the same time you should setup "rm -f" of the lock file during its stop phase.

See https://access.redhat.com/solutions/701383

Answer (score 1):

If you check what is in `/etc/rc0.d` and `/etc/rc6.d`, you will see that before you get to your service, the system will have run first a `killall` (priority 00), and then a `halt` (priority 01).

Although your service were scheduled to run next, the computer did already halt.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Sep 28  2012 S00killall -> ../init.d/killall
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Sep 28  2012 S01halt -> ../init.d/halt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Jul  8 21:16 S10test -> ../init.d/test
```

What I'd do if I were you, is to enable the script in runlevels you typically use,  say `345` and then swap start with stop, as all daemons which is chkconfig:ed to be running in your current runlevel will be called when halting and rebooting with the `stop` arg, *before* it gets to the services which it should *start*.

If you want your script to be run at the very last, before killing everything and then halting your computer, check what is the highest (mine's `K92iptables`, so for me that would be >92 for stop priority).

So `chkconfig --del baseRhel64` first, then alter the script so that `chkconfig` line reads `# chkconfig: 345 10 93`

Your script would then look something like this, with start and stop function names swapped:

```
#!/bin/sh

#chkconfig --list
# chkconfig: 345 10 93

stop(){
    echo "`basename $0` stop"
    touch /root/installscripts/test1
}

start(){
    echo "`basename $0` start"
    touch /root/installscripts/test2
    touch /root/installscripts/"`basename $0`"
}

case "$1" in
    start) start;;
    stop) stop;;
    *);;
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
    RETCAL=1
esac
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a fine solution for you
a)A script like this

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# localshutdown
#
# chkconfig:   06 01 25
# description: localshutdown script
#              

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: 
# Required-Start: 
# Required-Stop: 
# Should-Start: 
# Should-Stop: 
# Default-Start: 0 6 
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: 
# Description:      
### END INIT INFO

# Source function library.

start() {
    echo "Your commands here"
    touch /root/funziona #use it for a test
}

stop() {
    echo "nothing" >/dev/null 2>&1
}

restart() {
    stop
    start
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        $1
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        $1
        ;;
    restart)
        restart
        ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 2
esac
exit $?
```

Then

```
chkconfig --add /etc/init.d/yourscript.sh
```

then

```
chkconfig --level 06 yourscript.sh on
chkconfig --level 12345 yourscript.sh off
```

Tested and working